JavaScript HTML Element remove method - undocumented bahavior
Some time ago I was refactoring some legacy JS code, when I noticed PHPStorm complaining about the use of remove function: mySelect.remove(0) - Invalid number of arguments, expected 0. I made a quick look to the docs and found no information about the argument so I deleted it without further investigation (my bad) and deployed changes.
Recently I've been reported a bug that browser freezes after changing some form element. It seems that my change has broken the form.
The relevant code is very simple:
const mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
while (mySelect.options.length > 0) {
    mySelect.remove();
}

With the proper call of remove the browser freezes as it looks like the loop is infinite, but changing the call to undocumented mySelect.remove(0) makes it work as expected.
Any ideas about that behavior?
[tested on Chrome]

PHPStorm can't help you more because it doesn't know mySelect is a select element; if you hover over mySelect in your code, you'll probably find it says HTMLElement. You could add e.g. a hint comment /** @type {HTMLSelectElement} */ before the const mySelect line to say that you expect this to be a HTMLSelectElement, and then you should probably see a more accurate signature for .remove().

undocumented documentation

off topic: "so I made changes and deployed without further investigation" - do you work for crowdstrike?

A brief explanation:
mySelect.remove(0) 

correctly removes the first option (index 0) from the select element on each iteration.
mySelect.remove() 

removes the entire select element from the DOM on the first iteration, resulting in an infinite loop because the condition mySelect.options.length > 0 is always true after the select element has been removed.
to avoid confusion you can also use this other method
while (mySelect.options.length > 0) {
    mySelect.removeChild(mySelect.options[0]);
}


Thank you for your answer. I wonder why this feature is not documented anywhere. I found no place neither on the web nor in PHPStorm built-in documentation mentioning this bahavior.

This is documented: "The HTMLSelectElement.remove() method must act like its namesake method on that same options collection when it has arguments, and like its namesake method on the ChildNode interface implemented by the HTMLSelectElement ancestor interface Element when it has no arguments."
